# Some word meaning difference and word choice

Tags: word-usage, usage

1. Is there any difference between go over there, come over there, come there, come here, go there, go here, go over and come over.
2. If it’s appropriate I ask customer “please come to the line at the counter to pay”,”please wait in that line at the counter.”?

Thanks a lot for anyone who could explain these to me.

Comment: Relevant: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/come-or-go

Answer (score 1):

go over there: Is correct, and used when you tell somebody standing next to you to go somewhere further away.

come over there: Wrong... You can say come over here, if you want somebody to come to a place located next to you.

go there: is rather slang form for go over there;

go here: not English, not logical. You can say go there or yet better go over there
go over: Wrong... say: go over there.
come over: Wrong... say: come over here.

“please come to the line at the counter to pay”: This is fine in the sense that it's English, but not natural. I may say: You may pay at the counter over there (smiling, of course), or more politely, would you please pay at the counter over there.

Hope this helps...